# How to solve Can't find referenced class warnings when building for Amazon?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, amazon-fire-os

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Here are the dependencies of my `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':chartboostSDK')
    compile project(':flurry_lib')
    compile project(':googleCloudMessaging_lib')
    compile project(':mainLibProj')
    compile project(':localytics_lib')
    compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1534')
    compile project(':unityandroidresources')
    compile project(':iAB_lib')
    compile project(':etcetera_lib')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/FlurryPlugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/FreshdeskPlugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/Prime31UnityActivity.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony-adapter-1.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-bridge.jar')
    compile files('libs/apsalar.jar')
    compile files('libs/apsalarUnity3d.jar')
    compile files('libs/bolts-android-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost-adapter-1.0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v5_4_3_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger.jar')
    compile files('libs/emojiplugin.jar')
    compile files('libs/in-app-purchasing-2.0.61.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/nativex-adapter-1.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyunitywrapper.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-adapter-1.1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/unity-classes.jar')
}
```

Here is the list of warnings

```
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptContent
Warning:com.vungle.publisher.location.GoogleLocationClientDetailedLocationProvider: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$OnConnectionFailedListener
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$2: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptManager
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptContent
Warning:com.supersonic.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge: can't find referenced class com.supersonic.adapters.hyprmx.HyprMXConfig
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$6: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$11: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAds
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$12: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAds
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.context.ContextManager
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.c.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.SimplePrompt
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.task.TaskManager
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.b: can't find referenced method 'void preExecution()' in program class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.UnreadUpdatesCallback
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.MobihelpConfig
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find superclass or interface com.amazon.android.framework.task.command.AbstractCommandTask
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.FeedbackType
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.h.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.vungle.publisher.location.GoogleLocationClientDetailedLocationProvider: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$OnConnectionFailedListener
Warning:com.supersonic.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge: can't find referenced class com.supersonic.adapters.unityads.UnityAdsConfig
Warning:com.supersonic.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge: can't find referenced class com.supersonic.adapters.flurry.FlurryConfig
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$12: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAdSize
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.supersonic.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge: can't find referenced class com.supersonic.adapters.applovin.AppLovinConfig
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.e.d: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAdListener
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.MobihelpConfig
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.a.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.SimplePrompt
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.task.command.AbstractCommandTask
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin: can't find superclass or interface com.flurry.android.FlurryAdListener
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.vungle.publisher.location.GoogleLocationClientDetailedLocationProvider: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.Kiwi
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.e.c: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.supersonic.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge: can't find referenced class com.supersonic.adapters.hyprmx.HyprMXConfig
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptContent
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.util.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.Kiwi
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$9: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAdSize
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$10: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAds
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.resource.Resource
Warning:com.vungle.publisher.location.GoogleLocationClientDetailedLocationProvider: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks
Warning:com.tapjoy.internal.a$g: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.licensing.LicenseFailurePromptContentMapper
Warning:com.tapjoy.internal.ii: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory getHttpSocketFactory(int,android.net.SSLSessionCache)' in library class android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
Warning:com.vungle.publisher.location.GoogleLocationClientDetailedLocationProvider: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.context.ContextManager
Warning:com.vungle.publisher.location.GoogleLocationClientDetailedLocationProvider: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$OnConnectionFailedListener
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.task.TaskManager
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.g.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.context.ContextManager
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a$1: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.context.ContextManager
Warning:com.supersonic.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge: can't find referenced class com.supersonic.adapters.applovin.AppLovinConfig
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.licensing.LicenseFailurePromptContentMapper
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport$1: can't find superclass or interface com.freshdesk.mobihelp.UnreadUpdatesCallback
Warning:com.tapjoy.internal.km: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$1: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.FeedbackType
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.Kiwi
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$9: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAds
Warning:com.supersonic.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge: can't find referenced class com.supersonic.adapters.unityads.UnityAdsConfig
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.vungle.publisher.location.GoogleLocationClientDetailedLocationProvider: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.c.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport$1: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.MobihelpCallbackStatus
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.Mobihelp
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.FailureResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.task.TaskManager
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$7: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
Warning:com.supersonic.unity.androidbridge.AndroidBridge: can't find referenced class com.supersonic.adapters.flurry.FlurryConfig
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$10: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAdSize
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.f: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.util.KiwiLogger
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$10: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAdSize
Warning:com.vungle.publisher.location.GoogleLocationClientDetailedLocationProvider: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient$ConnectionCallbacks
Warning:com.tapjoy.internal.ii$1: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory getHttpSocketFactory(int,android.net.SSLSessionCache)' in library class android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.MobihelpConfig
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.FailureResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.licensing.LicenseFailurePromptContentMapper
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$5: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.MobihelpConfig
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.a.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a$1: can't find superclass or interface com.amazon.android.framework.task.Task
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.d.d: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.g.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.c.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.task.pipeline.TaskPipelineId
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.f.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.tapjoy.internal.a$h: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.d.c: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.e.c: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.FailureResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.resource.Resource
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$12: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAdSize
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.e.d: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a$1: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.task.Task
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.Mobihelp
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.h.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$9: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAdSize
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$3: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAdType
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$4: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptContent
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAds
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.task.pipeline.TaskPipelineId
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptContent
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.FeedbackType
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.venezia.command.SuccessResult
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.task.command.AbstractCommandTask
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b: can't find superclass or interface com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.SimplePrompt
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.resource.Resource
Warning:com.prime31.FlurryPlugin$8: can't find referenced class com.flurry.android.FlurryAds
Warning:com.freshdeskplugin.freshdesksupport.UnitySupport$1: can't find referenced class com.freshdesk.mobihelp.UnreadUpdatesCallback
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.b.a$1: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.context.ContextManager
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.d.b: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptContent
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.c.a: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.exception.KiwiException
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i: can't find referenced class com.amazon.android.framework.prompt.PromptManager
Warning:com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.d.b: can't find referenced method 'void preExecution()' in program class com.amazon.device.iap.internal.b.i
Warning:there were 214 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
         You may need to recompile the code.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.

Warning:there were 4 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:starChef:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
```

Comment: _Please correct the above warnings first_: Post the above warnings and the output of `gradle dependencies`

Comment: Done..Please go though

Comment: are you having trouble when trying to build you apk to release?

Comment: Yes, Gururat Santana, the trouble is when I am trying to build apk to release

Answer (score 3):

Normally [Amazon suggests](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs/code-obfuscation) including the following in your ProGuard configuration file:

```
-dontwarn com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazon.** {*;}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

and also skipping ProGuard's optimization:

```
-dontoptimize
```

However, in my personal experience, including suggestions from numerous other SO posts, none of that worked. In the end I had to turn off obfuscation (`minifyEnabled false`) to build for Amazon, which produced the release build:

```
android {
...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
        'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

You may also want to experiment by adding this to your ProGuard settings:

```
-dontshrink
-keep class org.apache.** {*;}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Comment: what is Proguard configuration file ?

Comment: That would be the proguard-rules.pro file.

Comment: I just have a proguard-rules.txt file. Is it the same ?

Comment: It's called proguard-project.txt and it's normally in the project folder (the same location where you put your google-services.json file).

Comment: I used the -dontwarn thing, but it seems to make no difference. 
And I cannot set minifyEnabled as false since the very role assigned to me is to implement proguard :(

Answer (score 0):

May be you are mismatching between

- sdk version
- Build Tools
- Gradle Plugins

  in terms of compatibility.

To resolve it, verify that you are using the latest versions of them. The gradle plugins are placed in the build.gradle of the project, and the other versions are on the build.gradle of the module.
For example, for SDK 23, you can use the Build Tools 23.0.1 and gradle plugins version 1.3.1.

clean it after change settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several modules in your project, try to add

```
-dontwarn com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazon.** {*;}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontoptimize
```

to each `proguard-rules.pro` file in these modules.

For example, if you have two modules: `base` and `installed`, add the lines to both files:

- base/proguard-rules.pro
- installed/proguard-rules.pro